# Finding a subset of a compact connected Hausdorff space with a certain property

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a compact connected Hausdorff space, and that $D$ is a proper compact connected subset of $X$ with non-empty interior. I am trying to show that there exists a compact connected subset $C$ of $X$ such that $C \not \subseteq D$, $D \not \subseteq C$, and $C \cap D \neq \emptyset$.

In an earlier question I showed that for a proper subset $E$ of a compact connected Hausdorff space $X$, and a component $F$ of $E$, we have that $E \cap F \setminus int(D) \neq \emptyset$. Perhaps this is helpful? So far I have not gotten anywhere.

Comment: Have you made an advance in this problem?  
Also, can you please rewrite what you proved in an earlier question? This isn't very clear. For example, if $F$ is a component of $E$, we have $E \cap F = F$.